# Try/catch VS fopen (to check valid file's URL)

Tags: php, error-handling, try-catch, fopen

Hi there I want to check error-handling for an external URL (film/images) to know it is valid or not.(in my server)

I Found 2 methods:

First: try-catch method

```
try {
    $path = savePic(...);
} 
catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    // exception handler code here
    // ...
}
```

Or something like this:

```
if($file = fopen ($url, "rb")
{
    $path = savePic($file);
}
else
{
  // URL is invalid
}
```

Which one is better and faster for a large file?

Is there a better method to do it?
}

Comment: This is not a question that can be clearly answered. it asks for an opinion.

Comment: Dose  my server must download file to underestand is it valid? do both of these method do it?

Comment: Here is a related question that may help you to decide if you want to use one of the above or perhaps using both and wrap file operation in try/catch. Link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24754161/2777098